# Display JSON data on a page as a expandable/collapsible list

Tags: javascript, python, json, list, tree

I need help with with displaying JSON data on a page like expandable/collapsible list.

Here is a valid JSON I`ve made converting from XML with Python:

[JSON Data](http://pastebin.com/tmZrpDYM)

And to display it I`m usig this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title>JSON Tree View</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<script>
function json_tree(object){
        var json="<ul>";
        for(prop in object){
            var value = object[prop];
            switch (typeof(value)){
                case "object":
                    var token = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,16);
                    json += "<li><a class='label' href='#"+token+"' data-toggle='collapse'>"+prop+"="+value+"</a><div id='"+token+"' class='collapse'>"+json_tree(value)+"</div></li>";
                break;
                default:
                json += "<li>"+prop+"="+value+"</li>";
            }
        }
        return json+"</ul>";
}
</script>
<body style="margin: 40px;">
<h3>Paste JSON Into The Textarea Below and Click 'Build Tree'</h3>

<textarea id="json" style="width: 100%;min-height:300px;">

</textarea>
<button onclick="$('#output').html(json_tree(JSON.parse($('#json').val())));">Build Tree</button>
<div id="output">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I get:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5umdI.jpg)

I need help "filltering" (or merge with upper node) those "0" and "1", and also - how to show only values of the attributes without the names (or if do you have some better idea how can I 
dusplay this list)?

Comment: Please don't use image, but write the example code (a piece) in the question.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but I'd use your browser's debugger and inspector to look at those object string representations and see what methods/properties are available for showing them more prettily.

Comment: To add to existing answers, and if jQuery is acceptable, i found the following to have comparably good design and features:  https://github.com/abodelot/jquery.json-viewer

Answer (score 18):

#### a **good-looking, compact, collapsible tree view**

[pgrabovets' `json-view`](https://github.com/pgrabovets/json-view) is amazingly clean and well designed.

Check out [the demo](http://pgrabovets.github.io/json-view/)

Answer (score 9):

If you can consider using JS libraries , consider using [JSON Formatter](https://github.com/mohsen1/json-formatter-js) or [Render JSON](https://github.com/caldwell/renderjson).
Both these libraries offer configuration options like themes, maximum depth and sorting.
To display simple JSON string in a collapsible form using Render JSON, you can use

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("test").appendChild(
        renderjson({ hello: [1,2,3,4], there: { a:1, b:2, c:["hello", null] } })
    );
</script>
```

Comment: the render json one works beautifully! thanks for this answer!!. for anyone looking for the script tag to add the script directly from github :                                                 
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/caldwell/renderjson/master/renderjson.js"></script>

Answer (score 7):

Some of the links to the questions are no longer accessible. I assume you are looking for how to make a collapsible JSON view.

---

### TL;DR

you can jump to **Full code**.

the code is very short (200 lines↓, including [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/), comment, test code.)

### Inspire you on how to solve the problem.

This question in some skill is very much like how to make the table of contents. ([TOC](https://gist.github.com/CarsonSlovoka/bf7cd5a172c24e89fbe31915776b73e5#file-create-toc-html-L95-L104))

1. First of all, JSON data is like an object. All we need to do is to **add some more attributes** (key, depth, children, ...)  for each item.
2. Once these actions are done, all left is to **render**, and here is the pseudo-code for rendering.

   ```js
   render(node) {
     const divFlag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`<div style="margin-left:${node.depth * 18}px"></div>`)
     const divElem = divFlag.querySelector("div")
     const spanFlag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(
       `<span class="ms-2">${node.key} : ${node.value}</span>`
     )
     node.children.forEach(subNode => {
       const subElem = render(subNode)
       spanFlag.append(subElem)
     })
     divElem.append(spanFlag)
     return divElem
   }
   ```

### Full code

both CSS is not necessary.

- bootstrap: [ms-2](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/) (margin start)
- fontawesome: [fa-caret-right](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/caret-right?style=solid), [fa-caret-down](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/caret-down?style=solid) if you don't want to use it, you can use [▸(25B8)▶(25B6)▾(25BE)▼(25BC)](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%E2%96%B8%E2%96%B6%E2%96%BE%E2%96%BC) as the [before contents](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossOrigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ=="
      crossOrigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>

<script type="module">
  //  main script {Node, Tree, JsonView}
  class Node {
    /**
     * @description Add more attributes to the item.
     * @param {*} item
     * @param {*} key
     * @param {Node} parent
     * */
    constructor(item, key, parent) {
      this.key = key

      /** @param {string} */
      this.type = Array.isArray(item) ? "array" : typeof item

      /** @param {Number} */
      this.depth = parent ? parent.depth + 1 : 0
      this.value = item
      this.parent = parent

      /** @param {[Node]} */
      this.children = []
    }
  }

  class Tree {
    /**
     * @description Given the root node, it will complete the children of it.
     * @param {Node} rootNode
     */
    constructor(rootNode) {
      this.root = rootNode

      const obj = this.root.value
      if (!(obj instanceof Object)) { // Array is an Object too.
        return
      }
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(keyOrIdx => {
        const value = obj[keyOrIdx]
        const subNode = new Node(value, keyOrIdx, rootNode)
        const subTree = new Tree(subNode)
        rootNode.children.push(subTree.root)
      })
    }

    /**
     * @param {string | Object} jsonData
     * @return {Tree}
     */
    static CreateTree(jsonData) {
      jsonData = typeof jsonData === "string" ? JSON.parse(jsonData) : jsonData
      const rootNode = new Node(jsonData, "root", null)
      return new Tree(rootNode)
    }
  }

  class JsonView {
    static DefaultColorMap = {
      text: {
        string: "green",
        number: "#f9ae58",
        boolean: "#ca4ff8",
        array: "black",
        object: "black",
      },
      bg: {
        object: undefined,
        // ... You can add more by yourself. They are like the text as above.
      }
    }

    static NewConfig() {
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JsonView.DefaultColorMap))
    }

    static SEPARATOR = " : "

    /** @type {Tree} */
    #tree

    /**
     * @param {Tree} tree
     * */
    constructor(tree) {
      this.#tree = tree
    }

    /**
     * @param {Node} node
     * @param {Object} colorMap
     */
    #render(node, colorMap = JsonView.DefaultColorMap) {
      /**
       * @param {Node} node
       * */
      const getValue = (node) => {
        const typeName = node.type
        switch (typeName) {
          case "object":
            return `object {${Object.keys(node.value).length}}`
          case "array":
            return `array [${Object.keys(node.value).length}]`
          default:
            return node.value
        }
      }

      const arrowIcon = ["object", "array"].includes(node.type) ? `<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>` : ""
      const divFlag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`<div style="margin-left:${node.depth * 18}px">${arrowIcon}</div>`)
      const divElem = divFlag.querySelector("div")

      const textColor = colorMap.text[node.type] !== undefined ? `color:${colorMap.text[node.type]}` : ""
      const bgColor = colorMap.bg[node.type] !== undefined ? `background-color:${colorMap.bg[node.type]}` : ""
      const valueStyle = (textColor + bgColor).length > 0 ? `style=${[textColor, bgColor].join(";")}` : ""

      const keyName = node.depth !== 0 ? node.key + JsonView.SEPARATOR : "" // depth = 0 its key is "root" which is created by the system, so ignore it.
      const spanFlag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(
        `<span class="ms-2">${keyName}<span ${valueStyle}>${getValue(node)}</span></span>`
      )

      const isCollapsible = ["object", "array"].includes(node.type)

      node.children.forEach(subNode => {
        const subElem = this.#render(subNode, colorMap)

        if (isCollapsible) {
          divFlag.querySelector(`i`).addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            e.stopPropagation()
            subElem.dataset.toggle = subElem.dataset.toggle === undefined ? "none" :
              subElem.dataset.toggle === "none" ? "" : "none"

            e.target.className = subElem.dataset.toggle === "none" ? "fas fa-caret-right" : "fas fa-caret-down" // Change the icon to ▶ or ▼

            subElem.querySelectorAll(`*`).forEach(e => e.style.display = subElem.dataset.toggle)
          })
        }

        spanFlag.append(subElem)
      })
      divElem.append(spanFlag)
      return divElem
    }

    /**
     * @param {Element} targetElem
     * @param {?Object} colorMap
     */
    render(targetElem, colorMap = JsonView.DefaultColorMap) {
      targetElem.append(this.#render(this.#tree.root, colorMap))
    }
  }

  //  Below is Test
  function main(outputElem) {
    const testObj = {
      db: {
        port: 1234,
        name: "My db",
        tables: [
          {id: 1, name: "table 1"},
          {id: 2, name: "table 2"},
        ],
      },
      options: {
        debug: false,
        ui: true,
      },
      person: [
        "Foo", 
        "Bar"
      ]
    }
    const tree = Tree.CreateTree(testObj)
    const jsonView = new JsonView(tree)
    jsonView.render(outputElem)
    /* If you want to set the color by yourself, you can try as below
    const config = JsonView.NewConfig()
    config.bg.object = "red"
    jsonView.render(outputElem, config)
     */
  }

  (() => {
    window.onload = () => {
      main(document.body)
    }
  })()
</script>
```

*vanilla JavaScript*

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing stuff. Little addition. When a value is null it throwing exception. So it may be added after `switch (typeName)` - `if(node.value) ...`

Answer (score 1):

I used Carson Reply And it Work Like charm but null object problem as woto says.
change in script.

```
const getValue = (node) => {
        const typeName = node.type
        switch (typeName) {
          case "object":
            if (node.value !== null)
                return `object {${Object.keys(node.value).length}}`
            else
                return 'null'
          case "array":
            if (node.value !== null)
                return `array {${Object.keys(node.value).length}}`
            else
                return 'null'
          default:
            if (node.value !== null)
                return node.value
            else
                return 'null'
        }
      }
```

Comment: Also change out the line with 'arrowIcon' to prevent unwanted arrows appearing: ```const arrowIcon = ["object", "array"].includes(node.type) ? node.value !== null ? `<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>` : "" : ""```